# Reversing the "words" of a container with a bidirectional iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

I posted another snippet of code a few weeks back when I started learning C++. Here's my second try now that I have some time to play with this again. The goal is to write a generic algorithm for reversing the "words" of a container with a bidirectional iterator. Separators of words are any values that a functor parameter deems as a separator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

template<typename BidirIt>
void my_reverse(BidirIt first, BidirIt last)
{
  for(--last; first < last; ++first, --last)
    std::swap(*first, *last);
}

template<typename BidirIt, typename IsSeparatorTester>
void reverse_words(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, IsSeparatorTester issep)
{
  my_reverse(first, last);

  for(auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
    if(issep(*it)) {
      my_reverse(first, it);
      first = it;
      ++first;
    }
  }

  // we bail out of the loop before inverting last word
  my_reverse(first, last);
}

int main()
{
  std::string test { " this   is a   test   " };
  std::cout << test << std::endl;
  reverse_words(test.begin(), test.end(), isspace);
  std::cout << test << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As a comment, I know that STL has a reverse procedure, but I wanted to try to implement something similar myself.

Comment: You don't need the lamda. `reverse_words(test.begin(), test.end(), isspace);` will suffice.

Comment: OK, fixed. If that's the only complaint, then it's a hell of an improvement from my first C++ attempt. :)

Comment: No need to write your own reverse. There is already a `std::reverse()`

Comment: @LokiAstari: Check my last comment after the code...

Answer (score 5):

Although not relevant to the algorithm itself, you could still consider these basic things:

- [It's best to use `"\n"` instead of `std::endl` for newlines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)
- [You don't need a `return 0` at the end of `main()`; it will do this for you automatically.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)
- You should also add curly braces in `my_reverse()` for consistency and in case you'll need to add more to the loop.
- The name `IsSeparatorTester issep` seems odd as an argument. Perhaps it should be renamed to something like `Separator sep` since it's not performing an action (like a function) and should therefore be a noun.

  However, if you're mostly trying to reimplement `std::reverse()`, then you can leave it out this argument altogether.  There may not be many cases in which the user would choose something other than a space as a separator.